# What is going on with the constitutional court in Ukraine?

Tags: law, constitution, democracy, ukraine, judiciary

Recently, Ukrainian President Volodymyr Zelensky submitted a bill to the Verkhovna Rada (Supreme Council of Ukraine) [proposing to terminate the powers of all Constitutional Court judges](https://www.ukrinform.net/rubric-polytics/3126600-zelensky-proposes-terminating-powers-of-all-constitutional-court-judges.html).

It's a bit of a sudden move for a democratic state and I'm unsure if it is allowed by the Ukrainian constitution.

Since the Constitutional Court is part of the Judiciary and normally the executive won't/can't/shouldn't interfere with its normal operations, **what prompted Zelensky's unprecedented actions in this case?**

Comment: This is way too broad. Please identify a specific problem. "What's going on?" is rarely a good question because it invites for opinionated answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Council of Europe reported that](https://www.coe.int/en/web/human-rights-rule-of-law/-/ukraine-constitutional-court-declared-unconstitutional-criminal-code-provision-concerning-judges-liability):

> On 11 June, the Constitutional Court of Ukraine declared unconstitutional Article 375 of the Ukrainian Criminal Code, which provided for the liability of judges for the “delivery of a knowingly unfair judgment”.

So Judges could not be held liable for their own judgments.

Then [according to JKRINFORM](https://www.ukrinform.net/rubric-polytics/3126600-zelensky-proposes-terminating-powers-of-all-constitutional-court-judges.html),

> On October 27, the Constitutional Court declared unconstitutional Article 366-1 of the Criminal Code of Ukraine that provides for punishment for inaccurate declaration of assets.

Then,

> On October 28, the National Agency on Corruption Prevention (NACP) closed access to the unified state register of asset declarations in pursuance of a ruling of the Constitutional Court of Ukraine.

However,

> The NACP stated that Constitutional Court judges had made this decision in their own interests, as the agency found signs of some of them declaring inaccurate information.

So, it might appear that some Constitutional Judges were protecting their own interests when passing the above legislation.

So, then finally,

> On October 29, President Volodymyr Zelensky convened an urgent closed-door meeting of the National Security and Defense Council to determine measures for the immediate proper response of the state to new threats and challenges to national security and defense.

Which, I assume, led to,

> Ukrainian President Volodymyr Zelensky has submitted a bill to the Verkhovna Rada proposing to terminate the powers of all Constitutional Court judges.

and it is assumed the Constitutional Court Justices would be reelected (or re-appointed, I'm not sure which it would be) only after submitting accurate declarations of assets.